# how do i manipulate the path name so it doesn't print out the entire name

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm new to programming. i need to index three separate txt files. And do a search from an input. When i do a print it gives me the entire path name. i would like to print the txt file name.

i've trying using os.list in the function

```
import os
import time
import string
import os.path
import sys

word_occurrences= {}

def index_text_file (txt_filename,ind_filename, delimiter_chars=",.;:!?"):
    try:
        txt_fil = open(txt_filename, "r")
        fileString = txt_fil.read()
        for word in fileString.split():
            if word in word_occurrences:
                word_occurrences[word] += 1
            else:#
                word_occurrences [word] = 1
        word_keys = word_occurrences.keys()
        print ("{} unique words found in".format(len(word_keys)),txt_filename)
        word_keys = word_occurrences.keys()
        sorted(word_keys)
    except IOError as ioe: #if the file can't be opened
        sys.stderr.write ("Caught IOError:"+ repr(ioe) + "/n")
        sys.exit (1)

index_text_file("/Users/z007881/Documents/ABooks_search/CODE/booksearch/book3.txt","/Users/z007881/Documents/ABooks_search/CODE/booksearch/book3.idx")
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(base) 8c85908188d1:CODE z007881$ python3 indexed.py
9395 unique words found in /Users/z007881/Documents/ABooks_search/CODE/booksearch/book3.t
xt

i would like it to say 9395 unique words found in book3.txt

Comment: Could you format your code please? Highlight it all and press `CTRL + K`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to split the path on the directory separator `/` and pick the last element:

```py
file_name = txt_filename.split("/")[-1]

# ...
# Then:
print("{} unique words found in".format(len(word_keys)), file_name)

# I would prefer using an fstring, unless your Python version is too old:
print(f"{len(word_keys)} found in {file_name}")
```

I strongly advise to change the name of `txt_filename` into something less misleading like `txt_filepath`, since it does not contain a file name but a whole path (including, but not limited to, the file name).

Comment: The parens in the question's `format` line look fine to me. You moved the parens around, though, and the line you present here will ignore `file_name` completely.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I don't know what I was thinking.